# How to configure Renovate to watch latest commits from branch

Tags: continuous-integration, composer-php, renovate

I want to pull the latest changes from the repository `roave/security-advisories` by composer package. As this package doesn't have tags, but pushes all commits to the branch `latest`, typical configuration doesn't work.

So far I have tried the following configurations, but without success. The documentation doesn't describe such case.

```
        {
            "groupName": "security-advisories",
            "matchManagers": ["composer"],
            "matchPackageNames": ["roave/security-advisories"],
            "matchBaseBranches": ["latest"]
        }
```

And for the last line:

```
"followTag": ["latest"]
"followTag": ["dev-latest"]
"matchBaseBranches": ["latest"]
"matchBaseBranches": ["dev-latest"]
```